# IntelliJ SBT directory structure

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I created a new SBT project *HelloScala*, then I created a package  called *week6* and then a Scala worksheet under it. Eventually, I got the   following directory structure:

```
~/HelloScala/.idea
~/HelloScala/project 
~/HelloScala/src/main/scala 
~/HelloScala/src/main/scala-2.12/week6/hello.sc
```

However, when I put `package week6` in the worksheet hello.sc, IntelliJ warns that `Project names doesn't correspond to directories structure`. My questions are:

1. What should be the correct directory structure IntelliJ/SBT expects? Is it specified in some .xml file?
2. Notice that IntelliJ created two scala subdirectories, *scala* and *scala-2.12*. Is it correct? Or IntelliJ somehow failed to recognize the scala which had already existed but download and install another scala?

Thank you!

Comment: I started from scratch and tried the suggestion @Jun Zhang, @Darth, @themoah and put the package under src/main/scala, the problem persists. Worse, the problem is more than just a warning -- with `package xxx` as the first line in the worksheet, the there is no output in interactive mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don not use IntelliJ that often, but usually Scala packages should go into `src/main/scala`.
The structure of a Scala project is nothing too different from a Java one. Minimally you will need:

```
    myproject
    ├── build.sbt
    └── src
        └── main
            └── scala
                └── mypackage
```

which is a project with a single package, a SBT script and nothing else.

For a more complex example, a Scala project could look like:

```
    project
    ├── build.sbt
    ├── project
    ├── target
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   ├── java
        │   ├── resource
        │   └── scala
        └── test
            ├── java
            ├── resource
            └── scala
```

in which the `project` folder is used by SBT for various purposes, the `target` folder contains the compiled `.class` files and `.jar` packages.

To answer your questions:

1. The above structure is used implicitly by the SBT plugin. Maybe it is customizable, but in most cases it is suggested against doing this.
2. Your Scala source code should go into `src/main/scala`. I have no idea where does the other directory come from.

---

@sgu It seems I misunderstood your question and unfortunately I cannot leave a comment. The file "hello.sc" you are trying to deal with is treated by IntelliJ as a "Scala worksheet". I guess it is a REPL behind IntelliJ which evaluates as you edit. However it is not treated the same as a "Scala source file", so adding `package xxx` gives you the warning. If you want to create a package, the source files should be in ".scala" extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your source code under "main/scala" directory. "Scala-2.12" is the directory, that would be created with sbt under "project/target" after you compile/build it.

Comment: problem persist

Comment: Check out tutorial from sbt on directory structure http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Getting-Started/Directories.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking the Make project option on top of the scala sheet in Intellij Idea? I use that option when I need to import oher packages into one scala worksheet.